# Query on events with more than 1 contacts

Tags: apex, soql

I am querying on events that have more than 1 contact. But its not returning events having more than 1 contact. Please find below the code:

```
for(list<Event> events:[Select e.Start_Date_for_Activity__c,e.OwnerId,e.Objective_4__c,e.Objective_3__c,e.Objective_2__c,e.Objective_1__c,e.Isclosed__c,e.CreatedDate, e.Activity_name__c,e.Id,e.Activity_Budget__c, e.ActivityDate, e.AccountId, e.WhoId,e.Activity_Sub_Type__c,e.Activity_Type__c,e.Activity_Status__c From Event e 
                          where  e.Key_Activity__c = true and 
                                 CALENDAR_YEAR(e.Start_Date_for_Activity__c) =:TSPYear and 
                                 e.Account.Territory__c =:parameterTsp.Territory__c]) {  
  system.debug(events);
  for(event event: events) {
    system.debug(event.Whoid);
    newTspAPList.add(new Action_Plan__c(
      Date__c = event.Start_Date_for_Activity__c,
      Due_Date__c = event.ActivityDate,
      Completed__c = event.Isclosed__c,
      Name__c = event.Activity_name__c,
      Assigned_to__c = event.OwnerId,
      Activity_Budget__c = event.Activity_Budget__c,
      Obj1__c = event.Objective_1__c,
      Obj2__c = event.Objective_2__c,
      Obj3__c = event.Objective_3__c,
      Obj4__c = event.Objective_4__c,
      Territory_Sales_Plan__c = parameterTsp.Id,
      ActivityId__c=event.Id,
      Contact__c=event.WhoId,
      Activity_Sub_Type__c=event.Activity_Sub_Type__c,
      Activity_Type__c=event.Activity_Type__c,
      Status__c=event.Activity_Status__c));
  }
```

Comment: This is the same question asked here. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95303/query-on-events-with-more-than-1-contact

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Bharati. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In your previous post, you were provided comments to which you didn't respond asking for clarification or suggestions on how to solve your issue. Reposting the same question without first deleting the previous post and revising your question to improve it isn't helpful and only adds to the noise here.

Answer (score 1):

To find `events` with more than one `contact` or `lead`, you need to query the `EventWhoIds WHERE IsGroupEvent = true`. For more on these and other related `Event` fields, see the [Object Reference for Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm).